# Scheduler not updating package files

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, google-cloud-composer

I'm developing a DAG on Cloud Composer; my code is separated into a main python file and one package with subfolders, it looks like this:

```
my_dag1.py
package1/__init__.py
package1/functions.py
package1/package2/__init__.py
package1/package2/more_functions.py
```

---

I updated one of the functions on `package1/functions.py` to take an additional argument (and update the reference in `my_dag1.py`). The code would run correctly on my local environment and I was not getting any errors when running

```
gcloud beta composer environments run my-airflow-environment list_dags --location europe-west1
```

But the Web UI raised a python error

> TypeError: my_function() got an unexpected keyword argument
>   'new_argument'

---

- I have tried to rename the function and the error changed to
  `NameError: name 'my_function' is not defined`
- I tried changing the name of the DAG and to upload the files to the dag folder zipped and unzipped, but nothing worked.

The error disappeared only after I renamed the package folder.

---

I suspect the issue is related to the scheduler picking up `my_dag1.py` but not `package1/functions.py`. The error appeared out of nowhere as I have made similar updates on the previous weeks.

Any idea on how to fix this issue without refactoring the whole code structure?

---

**EDIT-1**

[Here's the link](http://The%20code%20would%20run%20correctly%20on%20my%20local%20environment%20and%20I%20was%20not%20getting%20any%20errors%20when%20running%20%20%20%20%20%20gcloud%20beta%20composer%20environments%20run%20my-airflow-environment%20list_dags%20--location%20europe-west1) to related discussion on Google Groups

Comment: Can you please share your imports from the relevant files?

Comment: The imports are using this syntax: `from package1.functions import my_function` and they work without issues in my local Airflow environment (and in Cloud Composer before I added the attribute to the function)

Comment: I experienced some issues like this on Cloud Composer (but not on local environment), and this is really a pain to debug. Did you try to delete your files (`gcloud beta composer environments storage dags delete --environment my-airflow-environment --location europe-west1 <your directory>`) and reupload them? It can also be an issue on the Web UI, but there is no way to restart the webserver on Cloud Composer. As a last resort, can you try to upload your files on a freshly created Cloud Composer environment and see if that works? That could help to isolate your problem.

Comment: I deleted all the files using the Cloud Storage web interface and that didn't help. I'll try the composer console command next time I come across the issue, and see if that makes any difference. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

I've run into a similar issue. the "Broken DAG" error won't dismiss in Web UI. I guess this is a cache bug in Web server of AirFlow.

- Background.

  1. I created a customized operator with [Airflow Plugin](https://airflow.apache.org/plugins.html) features.
  2. After I import the customized operator, the airflow Web UI keep shows the `Broken DAG` error says that it can't find the customized operator.
- Why I think it's a bug in Web server Airflow?

  1. I can manually run the DAG with the command `airflow test`, so the import should be correct.
  2. Even if I remove the related DAG file from the `/dags/` folder of airflow, the error still there.
- Here are What I did to resolve this issue.

  1. restart airflow web service. (sometimes you can resolve the issue only by this).
  2. **make sure no DAG is running**, restart airflow scheduler service.
  3. **make sure no DAG is running**, restart airflow worker

Hopefully, it can help someone has the same issue.

Comment: how did you restart airflow scheduler service?

Comment: `sudo systemctl restart airflow-scheduler`

Comment: Thanks, Kun but I'm clearly missing some background information - how does `systemctl` is associated/connected composer?

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the webserver with:

`gcloud beta composer environments restart-web-server ENVIRONMENT_NAME --location=LOCATION`